# How to in OneToMany ManyToOne relationship not to save a second time the owner

Tags: spring, rest, hibernate-mapping

I have two classes with the following relationship

Response:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="responses")
public class Response {
   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @JsonBackReference
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "idq")
   private Question question;
```

Question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="questions")
public class Question {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idq;
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Response> respons = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am trying to do some rest test with Postman and as the same time to populate the DB.
Post request looks good when I send a JSON Question object, here three different request

```
{
    "idT"   : 1,
    "num"   : 25,
    "quest" : "Ceci est la question 1"
}

{
    "idT"   : 2,
    "num"   : 26,
    "quest" : "Ceci est la question 2"
}

{
    "idT"   : 4,
    "num"   : 27,
    "quest" : "Ceci est la question 3"
}
```

Yet I try to send a response test with in it a reference to the question owner in the hope hibernate will notice that the question allready exists and will save only the response in the DB.

```
{
    "question"  : {
        "idq"   : 1,
        "idT"   : 1,
        "num"   : 25,
        "quest" : "Ceci est la question 1"
                },
    "car"  : "D",
    "resp" : "Ceci est la reponse numero 4",
    "idq" : 1
}
```

This is the result I don't want, the forth entry should not exist. I have given the question object number 1 here.

[image: DB]

At this point I don't know if I have to solve the problem through a better written controller or if there is a way to do it trough hibernate and annotations or if I have to improve something in the DB Table creation

This the entry in the response DB table. I am happy to see that hibernate has written the right reference idq.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using an Auto Increment column for idq, then DB generates an auto incremented unique id for the idq column.

When you again send a request (with idq=1), hibernate inserts it as a fresh entry as you may not be setting the idq column manually in the code.

If you wish to update the existing record then you can use
`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
which tries to update the older record(if it already exists) with the new data that is received in the request.

You can visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for more information

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I'm looking for.
I would like to see JPA+hibernate doing it on the web application side not on the mysql DB side. I'll try to see if there is something to do with the autoincrement